# Laravel: How to rollback column unique

Tags: laravel, unique

My table name is `customers` column is `mail`
I tried with syntax

```
 public function down()
{
    Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique('mail');
        $table->string('mail',255)->change();
        $table->string('first_name',255)->change();
        $table->string('first_name_reading',255)->change();
        $table->string('last_name',255)->change();
        $table->string('platform',255)->change();
    });
}
```

But it not work.

```
   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'mail'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter
   table `customers` drop index `mail`)
```

Can you give me your help! 
Please,

Comment: That should work, but you should show us the full `down()` migration function and the error message you receive. Consider also taking a look in the database to see if you *have* a unique key there, and what it's called.

Comment: 1091 Can't DROP 'mail'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter
   table `customers` drop index `mail`)

Comment: Well, no index exists with the name `mail`. Your original code in the question was the correct name - `$table->dropUnique('customers_mail_unique');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open mysql console and get correct index key name for customers table and use that with your code `$table->dropUnique('correct_name');`

```
SHOW INDEX FROM customers;
```

Comment: 1091 Can't DROP 'mail'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter
   table `customers` drop index `mail`)

Comment: It should be `$table->dropUnique('customers_mail_unique')`.

Comment: [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'customers_mail_unique'; check that column/
  key exists

Comment: Did You tried to check what indexes available `SHOW INDEX FROM customers;`?

Answer (score 2):

Even funnier, you can pass an array parameter to the `dropUnique` function and Laravel will generate the correct name for you. Try this:
`$table->dropUnique(['mail'])`.

Reference [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#dropping-indexes).